# Does any set of dominoes tile some common figure?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling

Let $D_1,\dots,D_n \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ be two-point sets, i.e. 'dominoes' (unlike common dominoes, these are not necessarily connected, but I couldn't come up with a better name).

> Does there always exist **finite** $B \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ that can be partitioned into disjoint translates of $D_i$ for all $i \in [n]$?

For instance, if $D_1= {\tiny  \square\square} , D_2 ={\tiny  \square}\hspace{-6.5pt}{\ ^{^{ _\square}}},$ one can simply take $B=\boxplus.$ However, if we add just one domino $D_3 = {\tiny  \square}\hspace{-1.4mm}{\ ^{^{ _\square}}},$ or two dominoes $D_3 = {\tiny  \square}\hspace{-1.4mm}{\ ^{^{ _\square}}}, D_4 = \hspace{-1.4mm}{\ ^{^{ _\square}}}\hspace{-1mm}{\tiny  \square},$ then the suitable shapes become much more complex:
\begin{align} 
& \large \square \square \phantom{\square \square \square \square \square \square \square} \large \large\square \square\\[-10pt]
\large \square & \large \square \square \square \phantom{\square \square \square \square \square} \square \square \square \square \\[-10pt]
\large \square & \large \square \square \square \phantom{\square \square \square \square \square} \square \square \square \square \\[-10pt]
\large\square \square & \large \square \square \phantom{\square \square \square \square \square} \square \square \square \square \square \square  \\[-10pt]
\large\square \square & \large \phantom{\square \square \square \square \square \square \square} \square \square \square \square \square \square \\[-10pt]
&\large \phantom{\square \square \square \square \square \square \square \square}\square \square \square \square \\[-10pt]
&\large \phantom{\square \square \square \square \square \square \square \square} \square \square \square \square \\[-10pt]
&\large \phantom{\square \square \square \square \square \square \square \square \square} \square \square  \\[-10pt]
\end{align}

I expect the answer to be negative in general, though I do not see a way to prove non-existence of the desired $B$ for some specific  sets of dominoes. Note that if we don't require $B$ to be finite, the question becomes trivial: one can always take $B = \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Assuming the negative answer, one can further ask how to decide, for a given set of dominoes, if such $B$ exists. Some related [polyomino tiling problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Tiling_with_polyominoes) are known to be NP-complete, and some are even undecidable. So, this question could also appear to be not so 'elementary' as it might look.

Finally, I am also interested in the natural generalization to $\mathbb{Z}^m$. Observe that the case $m=1$ is trivial. Indeed, if $D_i=\{0,d_i\}$ for all $i \in [n]$, then one can take $B=[2\cdot\text{lcm}(d_1,\dots,d_n)]$, where $\text{lcm}$ stands for the least common multiple.

Perhaps, the questions of this flavor have been already studied, but I was unable to find something related. Though this is not my field of research, so I probably missed something. Apologize in advance if this topic is well known.

Comment: The fist example in my question (the one for $D_1,D_2,D_3$) is due to Ilya Bogdanov. The second one is just the first one plus its reflection.

Comment: Here is a formulation in terms of polynomials: associate a 'rising' domino consisting of (0,0) and (m,n) with $p_{m,n}:=(1+x^my^n)$ and a 'falling' domino consisting of (0,0) and (r,-s) with $q_{r,s}=(x^r+y^s)$. Then for a given finite set of non-negative pairs $\{(m_i,n_i)\}\cup\{(r_j,s_j)\}$, the question is about the existence of a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ *with coefficients only $0$ and $1$* which is divisible by all the $p_{m_i,n_i}$ and by all the $q_{r_j,s_j}$. This formalizes the problem, but I have no idea whether it helps...

Comment: @Wolfgang: it is clear to me your condition is necessary, but is it sufficient? (Could there be some polynomial $f$ that is divisible by all of the $p$'s and $q$'s, but where the coefficients of the quotients are not all just 0's and 1's?)

Comment: @AnthonyQuas oops I didn't think about the quotients. You are right, they need to have 0/1 coefficients too. So I guess this encapsulation won't yield any more insights.

Comment: Your example for $\{D_1, D_2, D_3\}$ can easily be generalized to solve the only difficult possibility in any set of 3 dominoes! So a non-tiling set must consist of at least 4 elements.

Comment: If you relax the conditions by allowing "shapes with multiplicity" (i.e., each box in the shape has a positive integer attached, indicating how many times that box needs to be covered by a tile), then there is an easy solution with area $2^n$ (again, "area" is counted with multiplicity). Represent each $D_i$ with an ordered pair $(a_i,b_i)$ of integers, indicating the coordinates of one of its boxes relative to the other; then take all $2^n$ possible subset sums (with multiplicity) as the coordinates of the boxes of your shape. Unfortunately, I don't see how to eliminate the multiplicities.

Comment: Suppose that an (infinite) graph has three perfect matchings such that the union of any two consists of only cycles of length four. Then can the union of the three matchings have no finite connectivity component?

Comment: Is the $D_2$ domino two points stacked vertically? They render slightly offset for me.

Comment: If there's a positive answer, then I think there's also a positive answer when the dominoes are allowed to be arithmetic progressions of arbitrary length. Indeed, suppose we can tile with the dominoes $\{0,x\}$, $\{0,2x\}$, ... , $\{0,rx\}$, where $x\in\mathbb Z^2$. Then let $b\in B$ be such that $b-tx\notin B$ for all positive $t$. It follows that $b,b+x,\dots,b+(2r-1)x\in B$ and that if we use the domino $\{0,rx\}$ then we have to tile that portion in the obvious way. Then by induction the rest also partitions into copies of $\{0,x,\dots,(2r-1)x\}$.

Comment: @gowers : I think the induction here is not well founded. For example "xxxxxxxxoxxxxxxxx" can be tiled by "xx". "xox" and "xoox", but is not made of copies of "xxxxxx". (Here your $r=3$).  However the idea works for powers of 2, in that tiling, say, by "xx", "xox" and "xooox" is **equivalent** to tiling by "xxxxxxxx", etc. Perhaps you were assuming that there would be no gaps?

Comment: @Wolfgang If we assume the set $B$ is convex then the divisibility condition is necessary and sufficient. Maybe something can be done with that.

Comment: @WillSawin That sounds indeed interesting, though I don't see how you can link this to convexity. E.g. if a coefficient of a quotient is -1, you mean that must correspond to a "hole" somewhere? Well, maybe... But there might also be (in theory) coefficients >1, or do you have an easy argument there can't? I remember from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415921/flat-polynomials-with-factors-of-big-height) that a lot of things can happen.

Comment: @Wolfgang The key point is that convexity implies, for any $(p,q)\in \mathbb Z^2$, that the $i \in \mathbb Z$ such that $(a+ip, b+iq) \in B$ form an interval in $i$. Dividing the polynomial associated to $B$ by $1 + x^p y^q$, we can see that the quotient vanishes if and only if the length of the interval is even for all $a,b$, in which case we can tile by the domino $\{(0,0), (p,q)\}$.

Comment: This can be tiled by 6 different dominoes:
$\begin{align}\newcommand{\x}{\large\blacksquare}\newcommand{\o}{\large\phantom{\square}}
&\o\o\o\o\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\o\x\x\o\x\x\o\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\x\x\x\x\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\x\x\x\x\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\o\x\x\o\x\x\o\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]
&\o\o\o\o\x\x\\[-5pt]
\end{align}$

Comment: With a SAT solver one can get some nice pictures. Here's a figure tilable by $D_1, D_2, D_3, D_4$, and also by $D_1$ with a gap: [paste](https://pastebin.com/htrMTLQ7).
And here's one tilable by $D_1, D_2, D_4$, as well as gapped $D_1$ and $D_2$: [paste](https://pastebin.com/rmat6Y5t).
Both are smallest, in the sense that they have minimal bounding boxes.

Comment: Here are nicer pictures [pic1](https://i.imgur.com/fogt3v2.png) [pic2](https://i.imgur.com/UnHZ8Vq.png)

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov : awesome! I was breaking my head trying to find your second picture, to the point of becoming sure it wasn't possible! Would you know if a solution also exists without holes? (Ideally also convex, in some discrete sense.)

Comment: @gowers In fact, this 'arithmetic progressions' version of the problem was the initial one that I had in mind. I decided to post on MO only its 'domino' version as a nicer an 'simpler' special case. I havn't realised before that they might be equvalent!

Comment: @YaakovBaruch I feel that the idea of Timothy Gowers can be modified a bit to work correctly. As you noted, if a finite $B \subset \mathbb{Z}$  can be tiled by any of $\{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \dots, \{0,2^n\}$, then it consists of blocks of legth $2^{n+1}$. Assumption that $\{0,3\}$ also tiles $B$ does not imply that $B$ consists of blocks of length $3\cdot2^{n+1}$. However, it is the case if we suppose that both $\{0,3\}$ and $\{0,6\}$ also tile $B$.

Comment: It remains 'only' to check that we can add an arbitrary number of odd prime factors in the same manner :)

Comment: @LSpice I'm not goot at $\LaTeX$, and could'n find a way to place one squre right on top of another. If you click on the 'edit' button you can see my (horrible) way to get close to the desired picture. If you know a sane way to draw a vertical domino (and have some time), feel free to modify my post

Comment: @YaakovBaruch With my current setup I wouldn't be able to tell if there's no solution, or it's just larger than, say, $200 \times 200$. Also holes are necessary in some [similar settings](https://mathoverflow.net/a/317284/106512).

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov could you try to find $B$ that can be tiled by any of the dominos from $3\times 2$ rectangle (looks like there are 7 of them) or even from $3\times 3$ square (12 dominoes)?

Comment: Looks like I figured out the equivalence between the 'arithmetic progressions' and 'dominos' version of the problem, though the details are quite technical. I will try to write it down soon

Comment: @ArseniiSagdeev I've been crunching since but wasn't able to find answers for any larger collections. 6 or 7 small dominoes could be possible with some tricks, but 12 is defintely out of reach as it stands.

Comment: Here's empirical consideration for positive answer. Start with some initial cells (say, just one) and propagate greedily in lexicographical order. Precisely, if $(x, y)$ is the earliest unprocessed cell in the figure, put its remaining dominoes towards later cells, possibly adding new cells. This can only create cells within a certain non-straight angle. Note that if we reached a cell within the angle that wasn't covered at all, we may diverge and still add it to the set. The plan is to obtain two configurations up to $x \leq X$ so that one can be merged with the mirror of another...

Comment: (cont) Assuming positive density of "free" cells, we obtain $\exp(\Omega(X^2))$ different configurations, however "mergeability" of a configuration with another one is only decided by $\exp(O(X))$ bits about cells near the border. Thus, if the process is random enough (akin to certain cellular automata) we may expect a collision. Failure would imply a global invariant/structure in certain cases, which we currently know nothing of.

Comment: Just come back to this. I have nothing new to say other than to acknowledge that my idea was indeed not correct as I wrote it, though it seems from what people say that a suitably modified version could be.

Comment: Great question! I'm also very curious what the corresponding sets $B$ look like in a three-dimensional setting.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer to the original question!** *Proof that the ‘arithmetic progressions’ version of the problem is equivalent to the originally posted ‘dominoes’ version* based on the discussion in the comments above.

More formally, for ${\mathbf x} \in {\mathbb Z}^2\!\setminus\!(0,0)$ and $k \ge 2$, put $D_{k}({\mathbf x}) := \{0, {\mathbf x}, 2{\mathbf x}, \dots, (k-1){\mathbf x}\}$. One might ask the following.

**Question 1**
*Is it true that for all $n \in {\mathbb N}$, ${\mathbf x}_1,\dots,{\mathbf x}_n \in {\mathbb Z}^2\!\setminus\!(0,0)$, and $k_1,\dots,k_n \ge 2$, there exists a **finite** $B \subset {\mathbb Z}^2$ such that $D_{k_j}({\mathbf x}_j)$ tiles $B$ for all $j \in [n]$?*

Substitution $k_1=\dots=k_n=2$ trivially shows that this question generalize the original ‘dominoes’ one. However, this answer proves that they are in fact equivalent. This circumstance either provides a pretty generalization of the original question (if the answer to both is positive), or perhaps simplifies the search for a counterexample (otherwise).

We start the proof with some notation. Denote by $f(s)$ the least common multiple of all odd positive integers not larger than $s$. In particular, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(9) = 3^2\cdot5\cdot7$. Given $i \in {\mathbb N}$, denote the domino $\{0,i\}$ by $D(i)$. The main tool to prove the desired equivalence is the following technical statement.

**Proposition 1**
*There exists an increasing family $T(1) \subseteq T(3) \subseteq T(5) \subseteq \dots$  of finite subsets of ${\mathbb N}$ with the following property. For all odd $s \in {\mathbb N}$, there exists $n_0(s)$ such that for all $n \ge n_0(s)$, the following two statements are equivalent for all finite $A \subset {\mathbb Z}$:

$\hspace{5mm}$I) $\hspace{0.2mm}$ $D(i)$ tiles $A$ for all $i \in T(s) \cup \{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$,

$\hspace{5mm}$II) $A$ consists of blocks of length $f(s)\cdot2^n$.*

*Proof.* We begin with three simple observations.

**Observation 1.**
*For all $i, N \in {\mathbb N}$ such that $2i$ divides $N$, $D(i)$ tiles all finite $A \subset {\mathbb N}$ that consist of blocks of length $N$.*

**Observation 2.**
*For all $i,N \in {\mathbb N}$ such that $2i$ divides $N$, and all finite $A \subset {\mathbb N}$ such that $[N]\subseteq A$, $D(i)$ tiles $A$ if and only if $D(i)$ tiles $A \!\setminus\! [N]$.*

**Observation 3.**
*For all $i, N \in {\mathbb N}$ such that $i \le (N \! \mod 2i) < 2i$, and all finite $A \subset {\mathbb N}$ such that $D(i)$ tiles $A$, if $[N] \subseteq A$, then $N+1 \in A$.*

These observations have the following corollary.

**Lemma 1.**
*For all $n \in {\mathbb N}$ and all finite $A \subset {\mathbb Z}$, $D(i)$ tiles $A$ for all $i \in \{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$ if and only if $A$ consists of blocks of length $2^n$.*

*Proof.* Note that the ‘if’ part of the statement is trivial in the light of Observation 1. The proof in the other direction is by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, then there is nothing to do. So, assume that $n>1$ and $D(i)$ tiles $A$ for all $i \in \{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$. By the induction hypothesis, $A$ consists of blocks of length $2^{n-1}$. Without loss of generality, assume that $A \subset {\mathbb N}$ and $[2^{n-1}]\subset A$. Taking into account the fact that $D(2^{n-1})$ tiles $A$, and since $(2^{n-1} \! \mod 2\cdot2^{n-1}) = 2^{n-1}$, Observation 3 implies that $2^{n-1}+1 \in A$. Therefore, the ‘doubled’ segment $[2^n]$ belongs to $A$ as well (because $A$ consists of blocks of length $2^{n-1}$). Finally, Observation 2 implies that $D(i)$ tiles $A \!\setminus\! [2^n]$ for all $i \in \{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$ as well. This is sufficient to conclude that $A$ consists of blocks of length $2^{n}$. Indeed, one can replace $A$ with $A \!\setminus\! [2^n]$ and repeat the same argument to find another block of length $2^{n}$ in the beginning until the whole set is examined. $\square$

We prove Proposition 1 by induction on $s$. Note that the base case $s=1$ holds by Lemma 1 with $T(1)=\varnothing$ and $n_0(1)=1$. If $f(s)=f(s-2)$, then the statement of the induction step $(s-2 \to s)$ holds by the induction hypothesis with $T(s) = T(s-2)$ and $n_0(s)=n_0(s-2)$. So, let us assume without loss of generality that $f(s)>f(s-2)$, i.e., that $s=p^{\alpha}$, where $p$ is an odd prime, $\alpha \in {\mathbb N}$, and $f(s)=p\cdot f(s-2)$.

Note that the sequence $(f(s-2)\cdot2^n \! \mod 2s)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is periodic. Besides, $p^{\alpha-1}$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides each if its elements, and thus none of them equals $0$. Moreover, each next element is ‘twice the previous one’. Therefore, there exists $n_0(s) \ge \max\big(n_0(s-2), \log_2s\big)$ such that $s \le \big(f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)} \! \mod 2s\big) < 2s$, i.e., that
\begin{equation} 
f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)} = q_0\cdot(2s)+r_0, \hspace{10mm} (1)
\end{equation}
where $q_0 \in {\mathbb N}, s \le r_0 < 2s$.

We show that the statement of Proposition 1 holds with $T(s) = T(s-2)\cup\{s,2s,\dots,(p-1)s\}$ and with $n_0(s)$ constructed above. For all $n \ge n_0(s)$, the implication $(II) \to (I)$ is almost clear in the light of Observation 1 since $2i$ divides $f(s)\cdot2^n$ for all $i \in T(s) \cup \{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$ by construction. Indeed, the only non-trivial verification here is when $i \in \{s,2s,\dots,(p-1)s\}$. In this case, we represent $i$ as $(2j+1)s\cdot2^m$. Note that $2j+1 < p$ and thus $(2j+1)s$ divides $f(s)$, while $m < \log_2p \le \log_2s \le n_0(s) \le n$ and thus $2^{m+1}$ divides $2^n$.

To prove in the other direction, we fist fix an arbitrary finite $A \subset {\mathbb Z}$ that satisfies condition $(I)$ with $n = n_0(s)$. By the induction hypothesis, $A$ consists of blocks of length $f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}$. Without loss of generality, assume that $A \subset {\mathbb N}$ and $\big[f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}\big]\subseteq A$.

Recall that $D(s)$ tiles $A$. Thus, equality (1) along with Observation 3 applied with $s$ playing the role of $i$ and $f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}$ playing the role of $N$ implies that $f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}+1 \in A$. Hence, $A$ begins with at least two consecutive blocks of length $f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}$, i.e., $\big[2\cdot f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}\big]\subseteq A$.

We proceed in the same vein. Namely, given $2\le j \le p-1$, after the previous step we know that $\big[j\cdot f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}\big]\subseteq A$. Recall that $D(js)$ tiles $A$, and multiply both sides of (1) by $j$. Note that this allows to apply Observation 3 with $js$ playing the role of $i$ and $j\cdot f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}$ playing the role of $N$ to conclude that $j\cdot f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}+1 \in A$. Hence, $A$ begins with at least $j+1$ consecutive blocks of length $f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}$, i.e., $\big[(j+1)\cdot f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}\big]\subseteq A$.

After the $(p-1)^{th}$ step, we obtain that $\big[p\cdot f(s-2)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}\big] = \big[f(s)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}\big] \subseteq A$. Therefore, Observation 2 implies that $A \!\setminus\! \big[f(s)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}\big]$ also satisfies condition $(I)$ with $n = n_0(s)$. (Indeed, we have already checked all the required divisibilities during the proof of the implication $(II) \to (I)$.)  As in the proof if Lemma 1, this is sufficient to conclude that $A$ has the desired block structure. Indeed, one can replace $A$ with $A \!\setminus\! \big[f(s)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}\big]$ and repeat all the above argumentation to find another block of length $f(s)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}$ in the beginning until the whole set is examined. So, $A$ consists of blocks of length $f(s)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}$ which proves the implication $(I) \to (II)$ if $n=n_0(s)$.

To prove this implication in the general case, fix an arbitrary $n \ge n_0(s)$ and a finite $A\subset {\mathbb Z}$ that satisfies condition $(I)$. Note that on the one hand, $D(i)$ tiles $A$ for all $i \in T(s) \cup \big\{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n_0(s)-1}\big\}$, and thus $A$ consists of blocks of length $f(s)\cdot2^{n_0(s)}$ as shown in the previous paragraph. On the other hand, $D(i)$ tiles $A$ for all $i \in \{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$, and thus Lemma 1 implies that $A$ consists of blocks of length $2^n$. Therefore, $A$ in fact consists of blocks of length equal to the least common multiple of these two numbers, namely $f(s)\cdot2^{n}$ as desired. This completes the proof of the implication $(I) \to (II)$ in the general case and finishes the proof of Proposition 1 by induction on $s$. $\square$

**How does Proposition 1 help to prove the desired equivalence between the ‘arithmetic progressions’ and the the ‘dominoes’ versions of the original question?**

Well, first we note that for each $k$, there exist sufficiently large odd $s$ and $n\ge n_0(s)$ such that $k$ divides $f(s)\cdot2^n$. Therefore, by setting $T'(k) := T(s)\cup \{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$, we obtain the following corollary.

**Corollary 1**
*For all $k \in {\mathbb N}$, there exists a finite set $T'(k)\subset {\mathbb N}$ such that the following holds. For all finite $A \subset {\mathbb Z}$, if $D(i)$ tiles $A$ for all $i \in T'(k)$, then $A$ consists of blocks of length $k$.*

Second, we show that one can easily ‘increase the dimension’ of this statement.

**Corollary 2**
*In the above notation, for all $k \in {\mathbb N}$, ${\mathbf x} \in {\mathbb Z}^2\!\setminus\!(0,0)$, and a finite $B \subset {\mathbb Z}^2$, if $D_2(i{\mathbf x})$ tiles $B$ for all $i \in T'(k)$, then $D_k({\mathbf x})$ tiles $B$.*

*Proof.* The equivalence relation ‘$\mathbf{y}_1 \sim \mathbf{y}_2$ if and only if $\mathbf{y}_1 - \mathbf{y}_2 = z{\mathbf x}$ for some $z \in {\mathbb Z}$’ partitions $B$ into finitely many equivalence classes $B_1\sqcup\dots \sqcup B_m$, each of which has the form $B_j = \{\mathbf{y}_j+z{\mathbf x}: z \in A_j\}$ for some $\mathbf{y}_j \in {\mathbb Z}^2$ and some finite $A_j \subset {\mathbb Z}$. Note that $D_k({\mathbf x})$ and each domino of the form $D_2(i{\mathbf x})$ tiles $B$ if and only if it tiles $B_j$ for all $j \in [m]$. Hence, it is sufficient to deal with the equivalence classes separately.

So, we can assume without loss of generality that $B= \{\mathbf{y}+z{\mathbf x}: z \in A\}$, where $\mathbf{y} \in {\mathbb Z}^2$ and $A \subset {\mathbb Z}$ is finite. In this case, the bijection $\pi : B \to A$ defined by $\pi(\mathbf{y}+z{\mathbf x}) = z$ deduce Corollary 2 directly from Corollary 1. $\square$

Now it clear how to reduce Question 1 to the original ‘dominoes’ question. It is sufficient to replace each $D_{k_j}({\mathbf x}_j)$ with the set of dominoes $\big\{D_2(i{\mathbf x}_j): i \in T'(k_j)\big\}$ for all $j \in [n]$ and apply Corollary 2.

**Remark 1**
*It is clear that the same argumentation works not only on the plane but in ${\mathbb Z}^m$ for all $m \in {\mathbb N}$ as well.*

**Remark 2**
*Note that the set $T(s)$ has quite a comprehensible recursive structure. For instance, one can easily see that
\begin{equation*}
    |T(s)| = \sum_{p^\alpha \le s} (p-1) = \frac{s^2}{2\ln s} + O\Big(\frac{s^2}{\ln^2s}\Big)
\end{equation*}
as $s \to \infty$, where the sum is taken over all powers of odd primes. At the same time, the definition of $n_0(s)$ is rather implicit. However, it not hard do derive from the construction that
\begin{equation*}
    n_0(s) \le \sum_{p^\alpha \le s} \log_2p = \log_2 f(s)
\end{equation*}
for all odd $s$. To evaluate this sum for large values of $s$, observe that
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{p^\alpha \le s} \log_2p = \sum_{t \le s} \frac{\Lambda(t)}{\ln2} -\lfloor\log_2s\rfloor  =  \frac{\psi(s)}{\ln2} -\lfloor\log_2s\rfloor = \frac{s}{\ln2} + O\left(\frac{s}{\ln s}\right),
\end{equation*}
where $\Lambda(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are the [von Mangoldt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function) and the [second Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) functions respectively.*

Comment: It took me a couple of days but I wrote the whole thing down! But perhaps I overcomplicated it, and someone could prove this equivalence two or three times shorter...

Answer (score 1):

**What follows does not answer** (the original question or any other question), just some thoughts.

Let $\mathcal C_n$ be the set of all dominoes contained in a $n$-square (i.e. $n$ by $n$ square...there may be some ambiguity here depending on the definition of a domino, which to me is just a pair of the square-lattice points). As Timothy Chow indicated in a comment, a domino $D$ could be represented as an ordered pair $(a,b)$ of integers, indicating the coordinates of one of its boxes relative to the other. We prefer the notation
$\langle a,b\rangle$ (obviously suggesting a vector). So a domino which as a two-point set
is represented as, say, $\{(4,2),(3,9)\}$ is also represented, as a vector as $\langle 3-4,9-2\rangle$, i.e. $\langle-1,7\rangle$ (even if the latter is not as specific, since it does not indicate the point at which the domino is "applied."

So, $\mathcal C_2$ is the set of all non-zero vectors $\langle x,y\rangle$ where we may assume
for convenience that $y\ge0$ and if $y=0$ then $x>0$, and also $|x|\le2$ and $|y|\le2$.
In general $\mathcal C_n=\{\langle x,y\rangle\not=
\langle0,0\rangle: 0\le y\le n,{\mathrm{\ and\ }} -n\le x\le n\}$.

In particular, $\mathcal C_2=
\{\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 2,0\rangle,
\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle,
\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle,
\langle -1,1\rangle,\langle -2,1\rangle,
\langle -1,2\rangle,\langle -2,2\rangle,
\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 0,2\rangle\}.$

Some obvious observations. If there is a solution for each $\mathcal C_n$, then there is a solution
for every finite set of dominoes (as each such set  is contained in $\mathcal C_n$ for some large enough $n$). Conversely, if there a counterexample (a finite set of dominoes with no solution) then there is some smallest $n$ such that $\mathcal C_n$ has
no (finite) solution.

I tried to find a solution for $\mathcal C_2$ with pencil and (graph-)  paper. This is a bit of an ambitious task but a good exercise to get a feeling for the problem. When I started I was convinced that one ought to be able to come with a proof that there are no solutions for $\mathcal C_n$. The idea has something to do with those patterns in the "Game of Life" that keep propelling themselves through space, multiplying, spaceships that keep producing and launching smaller rockets (google it). The idea being that if $n$ is big enough then any potential solution would need keep growing (some indication towards this provided below) and would exceed any finite size (well, who knows, this is the question).

My paper-and-pencil experience seems to show that  the (potential) solution grows rapidly, initially, then, when it reaches a certain size it stalls, and it becomes more and more difficult to show it would keep growing. (A potential, and incomplete, solution is the intersection of all possible solutions, finite or infinite, and alternatively could be partially built starting from a certain supporting line and putting together certain building blocks. If these blocks are large enough and complicated enough, perhaps a certain complexity may be reached when the solutions must grow without bound. Perhaps I should call this something like a minimal partial solution, although, even if called minimal, it can be quite big.) So, I am allowing for the possibility that a solution exists, for each $C_n$ except that it would be very big and rather difficult to compute. (Perhaps one could show existence without producing a specific solution.)

A comment by Yaakov Baruch (Jul 5, 2022) shows a solution that could be tiled by six different dominoes, here it is:       \begin{align}\newcommand{\x}{\large\blacksquare}\newcommand{\o}{\large\phantom{\square}} &\o\o\o\o\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\x\x\o\x\x\o\x\x\\[-5pt] &\x\x\x\x\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\x\x\x\x\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\x\x\o\x\x\o\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\o\x\x\\[-5pt] \end{align}

The dominoes that cover is are $\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle -1,1\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle$, and $\langle -3,3\rangle.$
(Here for example $\langle 1,0\rangle$ is the same as $D_1$ in the notation of the OP.)

Note that \begin{align} &\o\o\o\o\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\o\x\x\end{align} is a solution
for the dominoes $\langle 1,0\rangle$ and
$\langle 0,1\rangle$ (though
not quite yet a solution for $\langle 1,1\rangle$ or $\langle -1,1\rangle$. The vector  $\langle 3,3\rangle$ is long enough so that when we translate the smaller solution by this vector, the original smaller solution does not intersect the translated copy, and as a result the union of the two is itself a solution for the set $\langle 1,0\rangle$,
$\langle 0,1\rangle$  AND  $\langle 3,3\rangle$ (and coincidentally, by a good choice, also a solution for $\langle 1,1\rangle$, as a perk).
\begin{align}\newcommand{\x}{\large\blacksquare}\newcommand{\o}{\large\phantom{\square}} &\o\o\o\o\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\o\o\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt] &\o\x\x\o\x\x\o\o\o\\[-5pt] &\x\x\x\x\o\o\o\o\o\o\\[-5pt] &\x\x\x\x\o\o\o\o\o\o\\[-5pt] &\o\x\x\o\o\o\o\o\o\\[-5pt]  \end{align}
(Next we translate this intermediate solution by
$\langle -3,3\rangle$ to obtain the solution tiled by all the six listed dominoes.)

The immediate observation is that we could use this idea to cheat, and produce solutions for arbitrarily large sets of vectors, as long as we add one vector
(or domino) at a time, and the vector we add is longer than the width of the solution obtained so far (in the respective direction), so that when we translate a solution, the copy does not intersect the original. I do not say that the vectors are picked in advance; rather, for every positive integer $k$ there are $k$ many dominoes (of rapidly increasing size) such that some solution (some plane set of points) is tiled by each of these dominoes.

So the main problem is to find a solution
that works for not only a large set of dominoes, but also works for a large set of dominoes, so that dominoes in a particular set have "comparable" (and perhaps "conflicting," with each other and getting into the way) size.

For me (with the paper-and-pencil approach)
$\mathcal C_2$ is already too big to handle.

Here are some related comments. Say $P$, as a set of square-grid points in the plane, were a finite (and hence bounded) solution for $\mathcal C_2$. Let $L$ be a horizontal line, supporting $P$ at the bottom.
(It is easy to see that any supporting line that touches $P$ in at least two points must have slope $0,\infty,\pm\frac12, \pm1$ or $\pm2.$ Also P has supporting lines with any of the slopes listed above.)

So let $L$ be a supporting line at the bottom,
and after a suitable translation we may assume that $P$ contains the origin, has no points with negative $y$-coordinates, and if $(x,0)\in P$ then $x\ge0.$
Now since $(0,0)\in P$ and $\langle 1,0\rangle, \langle 2,0\rangle\in\mathcal C_2$ it follows that
points $(1,0),(2,0)\in P.$ Since $(1,0)\in P$ and
$\langle 2,0\rangle\in\mathcal C_2$, but $(-1,0)\not\in P$, it follows that $(3,0)\in P$.
The set $\{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)\}$ forms a block of four neighboring points and it is a solution for the set $\{\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 2,0\rangle\}$ of dominoes: an elementary, basic building block, a
complete minimal solution for this restricted set of dominoes. If we were to remove this block, and if there are more points of $P$ in the $x$-axis then we could restart this process with the next leftmost such point, and the latter will be the starting point of another "horizontal" block of four neighboring points.
This argument works for not only supporting lines but for any horizontal line: If its intersection with $P$ is non-empty, then it could be partitioned into "horizontal" blocks of four neighboring points (each block having points distance $1$ apart).
A similar argument works for the intersection of $P$ with any line of slope $1$, since the dominoes
$\langle 1,1\rangle, \langle 2,2\rangle\in\mathcal C_2$. Such an intersection is partitioned into blocks of four points, each block of "slope" $1$ with distance between neighboring points $\sqrt2.$ Clearly also, vertical lines and lines with slope $-1$ that have intersections with $P$ must each be partitioned in a similar way into blocks of four.

This argument (for $\mathcal C_2$) does not work with lines of slope $\pm\frac12$ or $\pm2$ since for example  the domino
$\langle 1,2\rangle\in\mathcal C_2$ but the double-sized domino $\langle 2,4\rangle\not\in\mathcal C_2$. (Perhaps I should have thrown it in, and see what happens, but I didn't do so, this is a project for some other time. Also a project: what blocks would be present if say dominoes $\langle 1,0\rangle, \langle 2,0\rangle,\langle 5,0\rangle$ all belonged to the collection of dominoes at our disposal? In general how do the blocks depend on a collection of collinear dominoes, this problem ought to have been studied in one form or another.)

So, the set $P$ (that is a prospective finite solution for the $\mathcal C_2$-dominoes) must have intersections with every vertical, horizontal, or every line with slope $\pm1$ that is formed of blocks of four  (with distance $1$ or $\sqrt2$ between neighboring points within a block, depending on the slope). The intersection with each line of slope $\pm\frac12$ or $\pm2$ could also be partitioned into "blocks", but such blocks are trivial, they are simply the dominoes with respective slope.
This is easily seen to be a necessary and sufficient condition for a solution, for $\mathcal C_2$, and could, in principle, be used to build up such a solution. (E.g., used, to make more sense of the steps and implementation/programming of an algorithm to solve the problem on a computer... or to come up with a new app for phones to play a game that let the user attempt to build a solution for increasingly difficult subsets of $\mathcal C_2$, so now all people playing tetris in the subway will instead be playing building-block-dominoes, and as a result (a) we will become rich by selling the app, and (b) we will make the app report the best solutions to us and post them on MO ... ok back to the problem.)

So, we start with a supporting line, pick a point on it, and start making deductions/conclusions as to what other nearby points must necessarily belong to any minimal, partial solution (based on the "bloks-of-four" idea, described above, in the case for $\mathcal C_2$). Partial info is good enough to mark certain points as "necessarily" belonging to such a partial solution, for example if we are not quite sure if a certain block on a vertical line is "right here at this spot" or one unit upward, the two copies have three points in common that could be marked as necessarily belonging to a partial minimal solution.

I enclose some pictures (taken with a phone, made with pencil-and-paper ... I know they could be drawn better,but this is what I have for now).

[image: Figure 1, horisontal supporting line]

On Fig.1, a horizontal supporting line is used (supporting a prospective solution from the bottom).
It is assumed (going now from "points" to "squares", just different terminology) that no squares are present on the bottom horizontal line (orange),
and on the bottom horizontal ray(yellow). The (big) X's and O's mark locations of squares that must belong to every possible solution (assuming there is a square right next to where the yellow ray starts).
Use X's and O'r to hopefully spot some "parity" info, but I didn't. It is apparent that the resulting blob is big enough to conclude that the solution for $\mathcal C_2$ (if a finite solution does exist) must be quite complicated. After I run out of energy counting blocks-of-four (and apparently couldn't easily see any more squares that had to be added), then I marked a square - a tiny red Greek $\phi$ on the picture, as a square that I "postulate" would not belong to the solution, to see if I develop any contradiction from this. The squares that had to be added to the prospective solution under this additional assumption are marked with barely seen x's and o's in the corner of each such square. A surprisingly large number of such tiny x's and o's were added, just based on the "prohibition" of that red $\phi$-marked square. In the end I reached no pattern that would have to keep growing or propagating, so I couldn't rule out that a finite solution would exist, after all.

[image: Figure two, supporting line of slope minus one]

Fig.2 is similar, but for a supporting line (in orange) and ray(yellow) of slope $-1$. The blob seems pretty big, in essence based just on the assumption that we could not put points below (and to the left of) the supporting line (or on the ray), that the point at the start of the ray belongs to the solutions, and that the set of dominoes to satisfy (or to saturate for) is $\mathcal C_2.$ (Of course, a computer might be used to verify if what I got is correct, and whether it might grow a little bit further, perhaps I overlooked some more squares.)

[image: smaller set of dominoes]

After I missed some sleep, the next day I tried something more manageable (see the picture labeled $12\times19$). I only worked with the subset of
$\mathcal C_2$ consisting of dominoes $\{\langle  1,1\rangle, \langle-1,1\rangle, \langle 0,1\rangle, \langle 0,2\rangle\}.$ (I tend to think that $\langle  1,0\rangle$ was also supposed to be in, but maybe I forgot to watch for it, and I see now that it is not included.) So, intersections with vertical lines do consists of block-of-four (that is, on the left part of the picture, since the same solution is also shown at the right, but turned $90^\circ$ counterclockwise). Diagonally, on lines with slope $1$ or $-1$ the "blocks" are simple, just the $D_3$ and the $D_4$ dominoes, using the notation/pictures of the OP. (Or, alternatively, one could expand the terminology and talk about blocks of any even number of squares, on lines with slope $1$ of $-1$.)
(The squares marked with X's or O's belong to the solution, whereas squares marked with a dot do not, but are enclosed by other squares that do. The entire solution is contained in a $12\times19$ rectangle. My solution is of smaller size than those posted by Mikhail Tikhomirov in comments, Jul 7, 2022, but mine works only for a smaller and easier set of dominoes... though these sets may not be exactly contained in each other.)

I was drawing on a graph-paper rather mindlessly (I had a cold and fever, trying to keep myself busy with something), and didn't really come up with any smart way to use parity (or perhaps use congruences $\mod4$ or $\mod8$), or try to throw in some bigger set of dominoes that might necessarily make the prospective solution grow in size without any bound. (Again, the idea is akin to those self-propelling patterns in Conway's "Game of Life", which I have not studied carefully, for that matter.) I tend to not rule out that a solution exists for any set of dominoes, though parity considerations may perhaps rule out certain types of solutions (e.g. "convex" ones that have no gaps), and the solutions would grow very big and complex (which of course needs to be made more precise, rather than just making it sound scary). To attempt build a solution one may start with a VERY big closed curve
(say an ellipse, or a rectangle) put some squares on the periphery (i.e., on the circumference, edges) and try to grow the solution from the edges towards the inside (just an alternative or a variation, compared to starting with a point on a supporting line, or starting with any point and growing the solution "outward" in all possible directions.) Well, really I have no idea. This thing about "blocks" may deserve a closer look, in particular what blocks do we get for specific sets of dominoes.
Re the terminology, one may call blocks "polyominoes" but those are supposed to be connected, so perhaps introduce a new word "rigiominoes" (from "rigid") just a finite set of points in the plane that is rigid.
It is known that some polyominoes do not tile the plane: Could we find a set of dominoes so that one of the resulting "blocks" is a polyomino (or a rigiomino) that does not tile the plane? I do not have a good understanding of the problem, but posting what I have so far, anyway.

(I saw, just after posting the above, that I had overlooked another Jul 7, 2022 comment by Mikhail Tikhomirov with a link to a related question and answer where parity is indeed used to show non-existence to certain solutions...need to study that.)